# Vizualize online users

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization

For my website http://goout.cz/ I am trying to implement a *google-analytics-like* tool to vizualize my online users real-time. I would like to show it to the public, so it must look nice.

The backend is easy to implement and to get the data to the browser as well. But I am looking for a way how could it be done visualy on frontend.

I am looking for:

1. Inspiration, if someone else does the same real-time vizualization.
2. Any javascript tool, which would be helpful to achieve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather broad, and will likely be closed. Anyhow, I would recommend looking at the [D3 JavaScript](http://d3js.org) framework. It is very powerful and versatile.

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: In the end, I came up with following: http://goout.cz/online/